# Why $\mathbf{R}\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{R}(\mathbf{\omega}\times \mathbf{x}) == \mathbf{v}\cdot(\mathbf{\omega}\times \mathbf{x})$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Suppose $\mathbf{R}\in\mathrm{SO}(3)$, $\mathbf{\omega}\in\mathfrak{so}(3)$ and $\mathbf{R}=\exp(\mathbf{\omega}_{\times})$. We also have two arbitrary 3-D vectors $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^3$

Can anyone help to explain why 
$$
\mathbf{R}\mathbf{v}\cdot\mathbf{R}(\mathbf{\omega}\times \mathbf{x}) == \mathbf{v}\cdot(\mathbf{\omega}\times \mathbf{x})
$$

Many thanks!

Comment: Operators in $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ preserve inner product, don't they?

Comment: Sorry, I dont get the sentence "SO(3) preserve inner product", can you give an example?

Comment: $\langle Au, Av\rangle=\langle u, A^t Av\rangle=\langle u, v\rangle$, for $A^t A=\text{id}$.

Comment: Oh, I see! $Rv \cdot R = (Rv)^tR=v^tR^tR=v$. Thank you very much Cave!

Comment: You're welcome. I am wondering which college is it that demands Lie algebra before teaching some basic properties about orthogonal groups :)

Comment: I am major in CS, but I should have done a better job in my undergrad linear algebra course indeed. :p

Comment: Hi Cave, I wonder if you could recommend me a book about Lie Group and Algebra?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50882/discussion-between-cave-johnson-and-shuda-li).